# Where is Hyperledger fabric chaincode store location?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hypervisor

I used peer commond in cli container on chancode install.
chaincode name + varsion file was made on peer containers.
(location is /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes)

What is this? chaincode?
I am looking for chaincode after install.

Comment: Also keep in mind that docker images for the chaincode will be created and will persist even after clearing the containers, volumes, and networks.  You'll need to run `docker image ls` and then `docker image rm ...` (followed by the list of specific image ids of those chaincode images) to purge that cache and start your network / chaincode fresh.  Otherwise, using the same network / channel / chaincode / version name will pull that old image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chaincode package which is installed on the peer is technically the serialized bytes of a protobuf message.  The protobuf in a ChainDeploymentSpec message, which is defined in the "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer" package:

```
message ChaincodeDeploymentSpec {

    enum ExecutionEnvironment {
        DOCKER = 0;
        SYSTEM = 1;
    }

    ChaincodeSpec chaincode_spec = 1;
    // Controls when the chaincode becomes executable.
    google.protobuf.Timestamp effective_date = 2;
    bytes code_package = 3;
    ExecutionEnvironment exec_env=  4;

}
```

The actual chaincode source files are stored in a serialized archive file stored in the code_package field of the ChainDeploymentSpec.

Comment: Does code_package field of the ChainDeploymentSpec will be output to a file?.
When doing instantiate and invoke, I want to know whether it is calling from File or data in memory.

Comment: When you instantiate, the peer will unmarshal the package and then use the code_bytes to compile the chaincode which is then deployed in a Docker container.  When you invoke chaincode, the peer communicates with the chaincode container which was instantiated