# Where is the chain code stored in Hyperledger Fabric 1.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Where is the chain code stored in Hyperledger Fabric 1.3. I thought it was stored in /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes. But under /var/hyperledger there is no "production" directory. Please help.

Comment: Check the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455268/where-is-hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-store-location

Comment: Actually I need to delete old chain code that I no longer need and I am not sure how I can do that. In an earlier post it said that the chain code was in /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes and I could delete it there the un-used chain code.

Comment: If you already installed chain code on your peer you can execute the following command it will provide info about the installed chaincode including the path.                        peer chaincode list --installed

Comment: For more information in documentation visit the following link https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/peerchaincode.html